# How to display output in Pl/SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I was wondering if someone can help me figure out how to code so that it will display the output without me having to use the command select * from month_days when I run the program.

```
set serveroutput on

--- Drop Table
DROP TABLE MONTH_DAYS;
--- Create Table 
CREATE TABLE MONTH_DAYS(cnt number(2), Month_ Varchar(9),Days_ Number(2));

Declare
mons varchar2(10);
dats varchar2(10);
i Binary_integer := 0;

Begin
loop
i:= i+1;
if i = 13 then
exit;
end if;
insert into month_days(cnt, month_, days_)`enter code here`
values
(i, to_char(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i), 'Month'),
to_char(last_day(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i)), 'DD'));
end loop;
DBMS_Output.Put_Line('The Month and Days for the year 2020'||Month_|| ''||Days_);
end;
```

Comment: What is your question? What is your problem?

Comment: My question is that how do I change my code so that it display the output of the months and days also because it only display what I have in quote when I run the program.

Comment: If you want to just see the output you have already done it. IF you want to see the output in tabular format. What you do is change this to a function say  "insert_date" . then call it like select insert_date(12,1986) from dual;

Answer (score 2):

`Create or Replace function insert_date (mons varchar2, dats varchar2)

return varchar2

as

    i Binary_integer := 0;

       Begin

       loop

            i:= i+1;

            if i = 13 then

            exit;

            end if;

      insert into month_days(cnt, month_, days_)

      //enter code here Didn't understood what you are trying to do here

      values

     (i, to_char(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i), 'Month'),  to_char(last_day(add_months(to_date('20200112', 'YYYYDDMM'), i)), 'DD'));

       end loop;

    return 'The Month and Days for the year 2020'||Month_|| ''||Days_;

end;

select insert_date(12,2) from dual;`

Is this what you are looking for ??

I haven't tested this. I think it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
select
  rownum cnt,
  to_char(add_months(date '2020-12-01', rownum), 'Month') month_,
  to_char(last_day(add_months(date '2020-12-01', rownum)), 'DD')) days_
from
  dual
connect by
  level <= 12;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using sqlplus, try turning serveroutput on by using the following command.

> set serveroutput on

if using another client program, look up the documentation for enabling server output.